# Is it possible to unhide only specific overloaded method of Base class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading

```
#include <iostream>

class B
{
    public:
    virtual void f() {std::cout<<"Fi";}
    virtual void f(int) {std::cout<<"GI";}

};
class A : public B
{
    public:
    void f(double) {std::cout<<"HI";}   
    using B::f;//but I want to use only f(), not f(int)
};

int main () {
  A a;
  a.f();
  a.f(10);

  return 0;
}
```

Is it possible in derived class A unhide only f() overload? So a.f(10); would call A::f(double)

Comment: btw I wouldnt use this setup with public inheritance, though making the inheritance private doesnt change the question

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the using statement with a function that calls the base class method:

```
void f() { B::f(); }
```

Comment: I was wondering that maybe it's possible with the using statement, but seem like not

Answer (score 1):

For what you are attempting, make `A` use *protected* or *private* inheritance instead so `B`'s methods are not `public` in `A`. Then `A` can declare its own methods that call `B`'s methods internally.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class B
{
public:
    virtual void f() {std::cout<<"Fi";}
    virtual void f(int) {std::cout<<"GI";}
};

class A : protected B
{
public:
    void f(double) {std::cout<<"HI";}   
    void f() { B::f(); }
};

int main () {
  A a;
  a.f();
  a.f(10);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> FiHI

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/hqKFNS)

Comment: @ALX23z no, it doesn't. And as you can see in the demo I linked to, the code runs fine. When a derived class overridden method calls the base class virtual method it is overriding, virtual dispatch doesn't call the derived method again.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Wasn't aware that `B::f()` would explicitly call the B's version even if it is overridden. The virtual functions are very misleading.

Comment: As A::f(double) hides all B::f methods, for my question it doesn't matter what kind of inheritance will be used. Your code works exactly the same with class A : public B